# How to insert values from column A of table X to column B of table Y - and order them randomly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to collect the values from the column "EmployeeID" of the table "Employees" and insert them into the column "EmployeeID" of the table "Incident".
At the end, the Values in the rows of the column "EmployeeID" should be arranged randomly.

More precisely;
I created 10 employees with their ID's, counting from 1 up to 10.
Those Employees, in fact the ID's, should receive random Incidents to work on.
So ... there are 10 ID's to spread on all Incidents - which might be 1000s.

How do i do this?

It's just for personal exercise on the local maschine.
I googled, but didn't find an explicit answer to my problem.

Should be simple to solve for you champs. :)
May anyone help me, please?

---

NOTES:

1) I've already created a column called "EmployeeID" in the table "Incident", therefore I'll need an update statement, won't I?

2) Schema:

```
[dbo].[EmployeeType]
[dbo].[Company]
[dbo].[Division]
[dbo].[Team]
[dbo].[sysdiagrams]
[dbo].[Incident]
[dbo].[Employees]
```

3) 1. Pre-solution:

```
CREATE TABLE IncidentToEmployee
(
IncidentToEmployeeID    BIGINT  IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL,
EmployeeID              BIGINT                  NULL,
Incident                FLOAT                   NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (IncidentToEmployeeID)
)

INSERT  INTO IncidentToEmployee
        SELECT
                EmployeeID,
                Incident
        FROM    dbo.Employees,
                dbo.Incident
        ORDER BY NEWID()

SELECT * FROM IncidentToEmployee

GO
```

3) 2. Output by INNER JOIN ON

In case you are wondering about the "Alias" column;
Nobody really knows which persons are behind the ID's - that's why I used an Alias column.

```
SELECT      Employees.Alias,
            IncidentToEmployee.Incident
FROM        Employees
                        INNER JOIN
                                    IncidentToEmployee     ON
                                    Employees.EmployeeID = IncidentToEmployee.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Alias
```

**4) Final Solution**

As I mentioned, I added at first a column called "EmployeeID" already to my "Incident" table. That's why I couldn't use an INSERT INTO statement at first and had to use an UPDATE statement. I found the most suitable solution now - without creating a new table as I did as a pre-solution.
Take a look at the following code:

```
ALTER Table Incident
ADD EmployeeID  BIGINT  NULL

UPDATE Incident
SET Incident.EmployeeID = EmployeeID
FROM Incident INNER JOIN Employees
ON Incident = EmployeeID

        SELECT
                EmployeeID,
                Incident
        FROM    dbo.Employees,
                dbo.Incident
        ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Thank you all for your help - It took way longer to find a solution as I thought it would take; but I finally made it. Thanks!

Comment: If I don't use the TOP statement and SELECT all instead then everything works as expected - thank you very much! :) But ... would you please explain to a sql-noob why it would not be that clever to update the "Incident" table? I guess I'd get the same results with the right statement - we all haven't found yet of course - while updating the table with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I think you need to allocate different task to different user, a better approach will be to create a new table let's say `EmployeeIncidents` having columns Id(primary) , EmployeeID and IncidentID .

Now you can insert random EmployeesID and random IncidentID to new table, this way you will be able to keep records also ,
Updating Incident table will not be a smart choice.

```
INSERT  INTO EmployeeIncidents
        SELECT TOP ( 10 )
                EmployeesID ,
                IncidentID 
        FROM    dbo.Employees,
                dbo.Incident
        ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: Hey Suraj Singh,

Unfortunately it doesn't worked. There are still no entries in the column "EmployeeID". :(

Comment: @R4kash Please post your table schema !

Comment: Hope that images will be enough, because I am a bloody beginner of SQL. Not quite sure, what you mean ...

(I am not allowed to post images yet. I need 10 reputations at least. That's why I put the images on directupload)

See images below:

s7.directupload.net/file/d/3421/szulfvgy_png.htm s7.directupload.net/file/d/3421/lltapi3a_png.htm –

Comment: @R4kash I just want you to post your table structure.

Comment: Ah. There you go:

[dbo].[EmployeeType]
[dbo].[Company]
[dbo].[Division]
[dbo].[Team]
[dbo].[sysdiagrams]
[dbo].[Incident]
[dbo].[Employees]

Comment: Wow. That's weird. Take a look at this:

http://s14.directupload.net/file/d/3421/iaideyw6_png.htm

I mean; the statement seems to be right, but as far as you can see; only the rows were updated, which have no content at all.
Why had that happened?

Comment: thats because it inserts new rows, So you are getting 10 extra rows using above query .

Comment: Ah, i understood. BUT: That was not my intention.
I wanted to replace the NULLs with those VALUES - I'll still need an UPDATE statement, won't I?

Comment: I combined the two tables by using an INNER JOIN ON statement. Mission accomplished. :)

Comment: @R4kash Can you post your answer please ?

Comment: I did. Cast an eye on my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Written by hand, so may need to tweak syntax, but something like this should do it. The Rand() function will give the same value unless seeded, so you can see with something like date to get randomness.

```
Insert Into Incidents
Select Top 10 
  EmployeeID
From Employees
Order By
  Rand(GetDate())
```

Comment: This one doesn't work, because the columns were already created.
Won't I need an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood. Can't think of (non-precedural) way to do off the top of my head. May be back later. Upvoted question and am curious what others come up with.

Comment: So do I.
Thanks anyway for the try. :)

Comment: @R4kash - Please update your question then. Right now, it explicitly says " insert them into the column EmployeeID of the table Incidents."